# How to find the menu bar has x number of tabs visible on the page

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using the site `https://www.shoppersstop.com/` to practice Selenium web driver using Java.

I wanted to find that the menu bar has x number of tabs or all the tabs visible on the page. I can write method for each of the tab that is displayed on the page but I am unable to write a single method that finds all the elements visible on the menu.

Answer (score 0):

Selenium does support finding elements by xpath. To keep things simple, I would suggest get all elements matching the xpath you need and then filter only those that are needed.

If using Java 8, this should work:

```
driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class='lvl1']/li"))
    .filter(element -> element.isDisplayed())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

xPath Explanation: First, get me all 'ul' elements that have the class 'lvl1'; then get all 'li' elements that are found immediately inside these 'ul' elements.

There are of course other ways that you can use, especially if you owned the website. For example, if you knew that any visible element will have the class 'show-item', then you can compose your xPath as: "//ul[@class='lvl1']/li[@class='show-item']".